# How to Create ajax based infinite products loader

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, infinite-scroll

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.4.0.2.

I want a module for ajax based infinite products loader that should satisfy the following conditions.

1. That should give a button like this.

[image]

2. For example i'm in some 12th page if i want to see more details(wants to go product view page) of a product from there from product view page if want to go back to previous page that should load all 12 pages at a time.

I found many open source modules but nothing is fulfilling my requirements.

for that i'm following this [Article](http://turnkeye.com/blog/loading-products-with-ajax/) but i have a error something like

**ias is not a function**

Any Ideas ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I get that ias error when there is more than one instance of jQuery on the page. So make sure jQuery ias only appears once (check via view page source). Make sure you have jQuery noConflict just after you call your only jQuery instance.

If you've used a plugin, then check in admin, `system->configuration` then click the particular plugin's section (the developer of the ias plugin) on the left hand side. They usually allow you to switch their jQuery on or off.